# How to avoid circular import within django's tests dir?

Tags: python, django, testing, import

I'm trying to fix a circular import issue I'm having with Django tests.

My dir structure is:

```
app/tests:
  test_user_level01.py
  test_user_level02.py
```

Within each file I have classes to test get 200s and get 403s (among other classes). Users in level 2 should have all the get 200s that level 1 users have and users in level 1 should have all the get 403s that the level 2 users have. Thus I have a circular import.

Normally I would solve this with an absolute import but I can't figure out what that would be.

I've tried:

```
"""test_user_level01.py"""
from . import test_user_level02


"""test_user_level02.py"""
from . import test_user_level01
```

But this seems to give a circular import error (missing classes).

Thank you ahead of time for your help.

PS. The following doesn't work:

```
import app.tests.test_user_level01 as level01
```

OR:

```
import tests.test_user_level01 as level01
```

OR:

```
import .test_user_level01 as level01
```

Answer (score 0):

Move common code, i.e. code which is used in both `test_user_level01.py` and `test_user_level02.py`, to a separate file, e.g. `app/tests/common.py`, and then import from there. Don't forget to make `app/tests` a package (i.e. create `__init__.py` file in the dir).

```
"""test_user_level01.py"""
from app.tests.common import some_common_class_name


"""test_user_level02.py"""
from app.tests.common import some_common_class_name
```